# How to maintain consistent text and image positioning using CSS

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have a table containing a default profile image. Initially there may be no textual content and my CSS styling is created to allow the text to wrap around the default image.

I am having a problem trying to position the image statically, still allowing the text to wrap around the image and also have the text to begin vertical positioning near the top of the cell.

I am basically using CSS for my image as such:

```
.TextWrap {
    float:right;
    margin:10px;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

Then setting up my div elements for the image and text content like this:

```
<img class="TextWrap" src="@ViewBag.Photo" />
<div id="bio" style="position:relative;top:0px;">
     <div style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align:left;margin-left:15px;margin-right:15px;">@Model.Bio</div>                     
</div>
```

The problem can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/2mT4X/

In the Full Text example, both the text and image are positioned relatively around the same distance from the top of the page which is ideally what I'm trying to accomplish.

In the Partial Text example, you can see that both the text and image are still positioned relatively together but because there is less textual content, both elements have dropped to the approximately the center of the cell.

I would like to control the positioning of the text and image so both are always a set distance from the top of the cell (inclusive of the text wrapping) regardless of the number of characters for the text input.

What I am looking for would be similar to a vertical alignment to the top but Table Cells seem to ignore that styling attribute.

I am somewhat proficient with CSS but in no way an expert and could use some guidance for this.

Comment: Try `td { vertical-align: top; }`

Comment: td vertical-align is middle by default, that's why you need to reset it to top :) (info to add to answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the desired effect with this line:

```
td { vertical-align: top; }
```

What it does is aligning the top of the element with the top of the tallest element on that line.

**[jsFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/2mT4X/4/)**

Comment: Thanks, that was such a painfully simple solution that I feel like an idiot for even asking the question now. In my question I did say that attribute didn't seem to work on table cells but maybe I was using valign which is now deprecated. No excuses either way though. All answers were correct but I can only accept 1 and Daniel responded 1st. Thanks!

Comment: @Mark no problem Mark. And don't feel like an idiot. If you only knew how many idiotic mistakes I make, you would laugh :). And I think you handled the decision with picking accepted answer correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Give `vertical-align: top` to `td`

Here is the updated code.
http://jsfiddle.net/2mT4X/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
td { vertical-align: top; padding-top: 10px; }
```

to align content on top of the cell and add 10px padding to top.

http://jsfiddle.net/2mT4X/2/